# How to properly handle simultaneous persistence actions in Redux?

Tags: redux, react-redux

React application using Redux. A have a combined reducer, consisting of `appStateReducer` and `contestReducer`. Each of these two takes care of some part of the application data.
When action is performed, I want not only the respective state to be changed, but I also want to persistently save the new state, so that if the user reloads application page in the browser, the state would be preserved.
My idea is to add third reducer to take care only of save and load actions (each of the two sub-states separately).
Save and load will use IndexedDB, through `localbase` package. All of the db actions (add, get, update, delete) appear to be synchronous, i.e. there seems to be no real need to implement asynchronous actions. *UPDATE:* this is wrong, it is asynchronous, just some basic examples ignore it.

I am not sure how to handle the problem properly.

1. I will need a database connection object, a singleton, initialized once after page is loaded, which should be shared by all save/load actions regardless of which part of the state is to be stored or loaded. That would lead to a separate reducer working only with the db object. If I do this, the db reducer would have to have access to all the other sub-state, which is normally not the case in Redux.
2. Or, I could implement save and load action in each reducers separately, not a big deal, actually. But how to make the global db object accessible by the reducers?

It is as React application written in typescript and all components are implemented as classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have access to all data if you are using middleware, Example:

```
export const requestPost = (id) => (dispatch,getState) => {
  // You can make an bank for post and check If data exist or not
  const postState = getState().bank.posts.data;
  const found = postState?.find((post) => post.id === id);

  if (found) {
    dispatch({ type: SUCCESS.POST, data: found });
  } else {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST.POST });
    API.get(`/post/v2?id=${id}`)
      .then((res) => dispatch({ type: SUCCESS.POST, data: res.data[0] }))
      .catch((err) => errorHandler(err, FAILURE.POST));
  }
};
```

Just make and reducer for saving data on DB or somewhere and read them at the start.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not able to make this working in my typescript project. The only difference is that I call localbase.collection('config').doc('some-key').get().then( ... ).catch( ... ), but when I try to dispatch my correctly typed (or so it seems) action creator in index.tsx (store.dispatch( loadContestConfig()) I get error TS-2345. As if the store dispatch method would not see the dispatched action correctly (it complains about missing property 'type' - which is if course in every action creator return value)

Comment: SOLVED. Yes, this is the way to go. Error TS-2345 is another problem solved elsewhere.

Comment: Happy to help you :)